# Tkinter error after becoming .exe file using Pyinstaller

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have made a webscraping program using Selenium (Chrome webdriver) and BeautifulSoup with a simple GUI using Tkinter. It works as expected when I am running it with Thonny. However, after making the .exe file with pyinstaller, I got error below:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1547, in __call__
  File "app_jun.py", line 20, in click
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

Below is the command that I used to make .exe file in pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onedir app_jun.py
```

and here's my main code:

```
from tkinter import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
ChromeService = Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
url='https://bibit.id/reksadana.html'

reksadana=[]
x=[]
temp=[]
root = Tk()

def click():
    temp=[]
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service = ChromeService)
    browser.set_window_position(-10000,0)
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(5)
    html_source_code = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source_code, 'html.parser')
    browser.quit()
    
    table = soup.find('tbody')
    tbody = table.find_all('tr', class_='row-table')
    for data in tbody:
        td = data.find_all('td')
        for data in td:
            x.append(data.text)
            
    for i in x:
        temp.append(i)
        if len(temp) == 13:
            reksadana.append(temp)
            temp=[]
            
    today = str(date.today())
    with open('Reksadana'+today+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in reksadana:
            for q in i:
                f.write(str(q)+';')
            f.write('\n')

    label = Label(root, text='Saving Reksadana ')
    label.pack()
    
button = Button(root, text='Start Scraping!', command=click)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Does anybody have any insight as to why this is happening?
Sorry for my bad English btw